# How can I change the default startup directory for cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, registry

My Procedure last day as below

Click Start, Run and type **Regedit.exe**
Navigate to the following branch:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Command Processor**

In the right-pane, double-click Autorun and set the startup folder path as its data, preceded by “CD /d “. If `Autorun` value is missing, you need to create one, of type REG_EXPAND_SZ or **REG_SZ** in the above location.

Example: To set the startup directory to **D:\learning\perl**, set the Autorun value data to **CD /d D:\learning\perl**

Then I clicked Start, run and type **cmd**. It successfully. I could do perl practice more conveniently now.

But today, I find when I try to build my Visual Studio 2005 solution which included some Pre-build event Command like this: 
`perl.exe MyAppVersion.pl
perl.exe AttrScan.pl`

It doesn't work. Show error: **can't find the path**. 
I check the environment variable setting and find the variable-`path` and it's value-`c:\perl\bin\;` still exist.

Finially,
I try to removed the Regedit.exe configuration "Autorun" value and test again. 
The issue fixed.

I only changed the default startup directory for cmd.exe command. Why the pre-build event  perl command was impacted? (I am using winxp and activePerl 5.8)

Comment: I don't recommend to do that at all, as it can have many undesired consequences and affect other programs, specially if current directory is changed, as explained here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433. It's better to edit the command prompt shortcut (or duplicate it) to run a script at start with /k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Visual Studio is using cmd.exe to execute perl.exe. This is not unusual, and changing the registry as you have done can also impact other programs, not just Visual Studio.

Just do the CD /D manually or create a link to cmd.exe that sets d:\learning\perl as the starting directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed on windows 7 x64 that jdigitals suggestion to create a link that sets d:\learning\perl as the starting directory does not work. Cmd.exe will not take that as a legal parameter. Also, in Windows 7 the key refered to by brian d foy does not exist. So on windows 7 it just doesn't seem possible to get a cmd to start in the right directory if it is not on the system volume (C:). So as far as i'm concerned this isn't solved.

Comment: *So as far as i'm concerned this isn't solved* is not an answer to the question, and therefore shouldn't be posted as one. This space is for providing answers, as indicated by the fact that it's in the **Answers** space and the text area used to write is headed by **Your Answer**. When you've earned the comment privilege, you can leave comments to questions or answers to express an opinion, but you can't use this space to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this has nothing to do with Perl, but is a Windows problem:

I had the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Command Processor \ AutoRun` set to C:\Work.

When trying to use git from within vim, neither vim nor gvim worked with the vim-plugin.

*The working directory when an application was called was always forced to C:\Work.*

Even though I had the right file from a versioned repository opened in the editor, *and it found and used the git executable*, it looked in the wrong directory for the repository.
No matter if the file was opened from Windows with the mouse in gvim, or via cmd.exe in vim.

Removed the AutoRun String from the registry and all was fine.
**Executables that are listed in the PATH variable still can be found, but the working dir is wrong through being forced.** (That is my explanation from my observations just 2 mins ago.)